# i get parse error with this lines of codes

Tags: php, mysql, parse-error

```
<?php     

$button=$_GET['submit'];
$search=$_GET['search'];

if(!$search)
    echo "you did not enter a HAWB.";
else
{
        if(strlen($search)<=2)
            echo "Search term too short";
        else
            echo "You searched for <b> $search </b> <hr size='1'>";

            mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("cannot connect");
            mysql_select_db("trip");

            $search_exploded=explode("",$search);
            $x=0;
            $construct="";
            foreach($search_exploded as $search_each)
                    {
                            $x++;
                            if ($x==1)
                                $construct="keywords LIKE '%search_each%'";
                            else
                                $construct="OR keywords LIKE '%search_each%'";
                    }
            $construct="Select * from trip where $construct";
            $run=mysql_query($construct);

            $foundnum=mysql_num_rows($run);

            if($foundnum==0)
            `   echo "No results found";
            else
            {
                echo "$foundnum results found.<p>";

                while ($runrows=mysql_fetch_assoc($run);

                {

                        echo "<table border='1'>
                        <tr>
                        <th>TYPE</th>
                        <th>HAWB</th>
                        <th>DATE</th>
                        <th>TIME</th>
                        <th>PLATE NO.</th>
                        <th>NO. OF PIECES</th>
                        <th>CARGO MARSHAL</th>
                        <th>BY</th>
                        <th>REMARKS 1</th>
                        <th>REMARKS 2</th>
                        </tr>";
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['Type'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['HAWB'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['Date'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['Time'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['Plate_no'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['Pcs'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['Cargo_Marshal'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['By'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['Remarks1'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['Remarks2'] . "</td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                          }
                        echo "</table>";
                }
            }
     }  
?> //code formatted
```

Comment: adding some text into the body of your question,  explaining the code and possting the actual error message will get you question higher rated. As it stands this is a poorly structured question.

Comment: That's not readable. Use the code tag

Comment: Use a decent **IDE** with syntax highlighting and make the word a better place.

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($search_exploded as $search_each)
{
    $x++;
    if ($x==1)
        $construct="keywords LIKE '%search_each%'";
    else
        $construct="OR keywords LIKE '%search_each%'";
}
```

You forgot the `$` sign on `search_each`

```
foreach($search_exploded as $search_each)
{
    $x++;
    if ($x==1)
        $construct="keywords LIKE '%$search_each%'"; //you might have to escape the statement
    else
        $construct="OR keywords LIKE '%$search_each%'";
}
```

Also, please remember on your horizontal rule to close the tag. `<hr />` not `<hr>`

Answer (score 1):

if this is a new script you are writing, I strongly recommend moving to MySQLi instead of MySQL as it is now deprecated!

Your code is extremely sloppy! Take more time when writing your code and use a decent IDE!

Lets start here

```
    $construct="";
        foreach($search_exploded as $search_each)
                {
                        $x++;
                        if ($x==1) {
                            $construct="keywords LIKE '%search_each%'";
                        }
                        else {
                            $construct="OR keywords LIKE '%search_each%'";
                        }
                }
        $construct="SELECT * FROM trip WHERE $construct";
```

Why are you defining $construct as null and then immediately doing an if/else?
You're also making the query read in your else as `SELECT * FROM trip WHERE OR keywords LIKE..`
personally I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish there

```
%search_each%
```

Should be

```
%$search_each%
```

And personally the if/else variables should not be `$construct` but something like `$condition`

On line 33 you have a stray `

```
 while ($runrows=mysql_fetch_assoc($run);

            {
```

should NOT have `;`

You're opening your table INSIDE the while and then closing it outside
It should be

```
  {


     echo "$foundnum results found.<p>";
 echo "<table border='1'>
                        <tr>
                        <th>TYPE</th>
                        <th>HAWB</th>
                        <th>DATE</th>
                        <th>TIME</th>
                        <th>PLATE NO.</th>
                        <th>NO. OF PIECES</th>
                        <th>CARGO MARSHAL</th>
                        <th>BY</th>
                        <th>REMARKS 1</th>
                        <th>REMARKS 2</th>
                        </tr>";
                while ($runrows=mysql_fetch_assoc($run)
            {


                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['Type'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['HAWB'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['Date'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['Time'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['Plate_no'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['Pcs'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['Cargo_Marshal'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['By'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['Remarks1'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['Remarks2'] . "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                      }
                    echo "</table>";
            }
```

You also have a plethora of missing `{ }` braces!

I was initially going to rewrite in mysqli but I think it's something you need to learn by doing yourself.

EDIT!!!: You should clean (strip html/tags) ANYTHING you get from a user inputted form!